# rails crontab rake javascript runtime not find

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, runtime, rake, cron

first,

```
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'===libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
gem 'execjs'==========execjs (>= 0.3.0)
gem 'therubyracer'====therubyracer (0.11.4)
```

is exists in Gemfile

```
Gemfile.lock show (libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12),execjs (>= 0.3.0),therubyracer (0.11.4))
```

centos5.7 already have nodejs
Myproject no problem when i use rake but crontab is error.

my run .sh type file

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
cd /abc && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production sync:abc
```

errors

```
Warning: NLS_LANG is not set. fallback to US7ASCII.
rake aborted!
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/opt/app/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in autodetect'
/opt/app/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:inmodule:ExecJS'
/opt/app/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rbin '
/opt/app/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:inrequire'
/opt/app/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in block in require'
/opt/app/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:inblock in load_dependency'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install nodejs as above gem has an dependancy of it.  you will get the list of installation repository links here
https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

but as you mentioned nodjs is already installed. you can give the lib and include path while installing gem into your system.

and if you are unbuntu user you can install it by a command

apt-get install nodejs

Comment: yes,you are right @Amitkumar Jha,
old path is ruby path,
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ruby/bin
new path is my system path
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
and problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Find out where node is installed with `which node` and add that folder to your path in the bash script (usually /usr/local/bin).

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

If you are using node directly, it is sufficient to call `/usr/local/bin/node foo` instead of `node foo`.